# Как найти максимальное значение в таблице получаемой из подзапроса

Tags: mysql, sql

В подзапросе Я получаю таблицу с группированную по дате и для каждой этой даты представляется сумма продаж в эту дату, как теперь получить отсюда дату с максимальными суммарными продажами? предполагаю что нужно где то использовать WHERE или HAVING но все попытки были неудачными(

```
select *
from (
    select sum(total) as sum, date
    from sale
    group by date) as t;
```

Есть такой вариант но я делаю один и тот же запрос дважды как это можно оптимизировать?

```
select date 
from 
    (select sum(total) as sum, date
    from sale
    group by date) as t 
where sum = (
select max(sum)
from (
    select sum(total) as sum, date
    from sale
    group by date) as t);
```

Comment: отсортируйте по убыванию и возьмите первую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MySQL это решается добавлением LIMIT в запрос и сортировкой данных в нужном направлении.

Так как вам нужно максимальное значение, то сортируем от большего к меньшему(DESC) и выводим первую запись(LIMIT 1)

```
select sum(total) as sumTotal, date
from sale
group by date
order by sumTotal desc
limit 1;
```

PS: Не используйте всевдонимы столбцов, которые совпадают с зарезервированными словами и функциями.

UPD из комментариев: Что бы вывести только дату

```
select date from  (
    select sum(total) as sumTotal, date
    from sale
    group by date
    order by sumTotal desc
    limit 1
);
```

Comment: Если мне нужно получить только дату без суммы, придется делать еще один запрос который вернет только столбец date? или есть еще вариант?

Comment: @Soloway дополнил ответ

Comment: Без as + какой-нибудь псевдоним после последней скобки почему то выдает ошибку, в любом случае большое спасибо! (Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias)